# How to set a filtering scheme to data function input via ironpython?

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

I am executing a data function via ironpython, and the input is predefined (a column from an existing data table). Now I would like to filter this input by applying a filtering scheme to it. How do I do this? I only want to filter the input, not the data table behind it.

Edit: since I can create a copy of the data table, filtering the data table would be fine as well, if there is a way to do that outside of the visualization of the data table.

Comment: you could filter the data table, run the data function, then filter it back?

Comment: @GaiaPaolini If I could set a filter to a data table that would be great. Is there a way to do this? So far I only found guidance on how to set a filtering scheme to a data table plot, not to the data table itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your question of September 4 you were setting a filter to act on a data table.
This would work the same way. This example should help. It uses the *iris* dataset and has *myDataTable* as input of type DataTable.

You first set a filter on the *species* column, then run a data function called *my data function*, then reset the filter. The data function needs to be executed synchronously, and be set up to already accept a filtered data table as input.

You can modify it to save the current filter values and reset to them, rather than simply include all values.

```
import Spotfire.Dxp.Data
import Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Filters
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Filters import ListBoxFilter,FilterTypeIdentifiers
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data.DataFunctions import *

# define column to filter on and set filter
colName = "Species"
filter=Document.FilteringSchemes[0][myDataTable][myDataTable.Columns[colName]]
filter.TypeId = FilterTypeIdentifiers.ListBoxFilter
filter = filter.As[ListBoxFilter]()
tofilter = ["setosa", "versicolor"]
filter.IncludeAllValues=False
filter.SetSelection(tofilter)

#run data function synchronously
dataManager = Document.Data
for function in dataManager.DataFunctions:
    if function.Name == 'my data function':
        function.ExecuteSynchronously()

#reset filter
filter.IncludeAllValues=True
```

Comment: p.s. filters are applied to data tables, not to visualizations. One can set a visualization to pick up the filter or ignore it (in the Properties>Data tab)

Comment: Yes, I had forgotten about the hierarchy and made the wrong conclusion. Thank you!